# Get specific String in String

Tags: php, string

i have string like this:

```
hdahdsa jkasdhjsa USD 15,000 jshads hduasdo SN : 02604800000734987654 at  17/02/2022 18:04:47. Blabla bla bla sdsad dsada
```

i have tried like this:

```
$string = "hdahdsa jkasdhjsa USD 15,000 jshads hduasdo SN : 02604800000734987654 at  17/02/2022 18:04:47. Blabla bla bla sdsad dsada "
$array = explode(" ", $string);
foreach ($array as $text) {
    if(is_numeric($text)){
        $sn = $text;
                    }
}
```

only get $sn = 02604800000734987654

what is the best way get string like this?

```
$price = 15,000
$sn = 02604800000734987654
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ? Please refer to the [ask] section before asking a question.

Comment: hi, i have edit my post. thank you bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_numeric` will return **true** for an integer (`15`) or a float (`15.00`) but **15,000** is neither of those.

A quick fix would be to remove all commas before testing like so :

```
$matches = array();
$string = "hdahdsa jkasdhjsa USD 15,000 jshads hduasdo SN : 02604800000734987654 at  17/02/2022 18:04:47. Blabla bla bla sdsad dsada ";
$array = explode(" ", $string);
foreach ($array as $text) {
    if(is_numeric(str_replace(',', '', $text))){
        $matches[] = $text;
                    }
}
print_r($matches);
$price = $matches[0];
$sn = $matches[1];
```

---

Another solution would be to use **regex pattern** like

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/^[\s\S]+ ([0-9,]+) [\s\S]+ ([0-9]+) [\s\S]+$/m', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);

$price = $matches[1][0];
$sn = $matches[2][0];
```